# How to change ng-table pagination?

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

How to change ng-table pagination? Default values are 10, 25, 50, 100. I want to start with minimum of 100, and when I change count to be 100 pagination still starts from 10

$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
                page:1,
                count: 100
    }

Comment: You can use this as example http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/2 . Just build an algorithm to set the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

ng table on the init accepts two objects as parameters

```
var tableSettings = {},
    tableParams =  {
        counts: [100, 200, 300]
    },
    table = false;

table = new NgTableParams(tableSettings, tableParams);
```

on the second object you can declare the counts you want to show and use over the table.